# How should files be represented in a POST?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, facebook-ads-api

I'm using Python requests and trying to upload an image to Facebook Ads API server.

---

I can put the image in the body using `data`

```
requests.post(endpoint, data={'pic.jpg': open('pic.jpg', 'rb')})
```

and then when I print the body of the request, it looks like `pic.jpg=%FF%D8%FF%E0%00%10JFIF...` with a looong string of those %_ things (I guess those are the bytes?)

---

I can also put the image in the body using `files`

```
requests.post(endpoint, files={'pic.jpg': open('pic.jpg', 'rb')})
```

and then when I print the body of the request, it looks like

```
--7bfdd12d05f549f3953f32165da5900c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pic.jpg"; filename="pic.jpg"

????JFIFHH??C


!1AQ"q2??????#BRW?$3b????7Cr????...
```

with a ton more ?'s and weird symbols.

Which is correct, if either, for doing file upload? For the top one I get back `[]` from the Facebook API and for the second one I get back `null`.

Comment: What does the API documentation tell you? When you use `files`, the `multipart/form-data` encoding is used, which is **usually** the correct method.

Comment: The API documentation does not tell me anything :((

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adimage/

Comment: The `-F` switch on the `curl` command appears to be the documentation. I indeed don't see anything else there, so I think the API authors are assuming a certain familiarity with HTTP and POST encodings.

Comment: Ok, so that would indicate that `multipart/form-data` should be used, which would mean `files` is the way to go? That seems right but I still don't get the nice response so I guess I'll have to keep digging.

Comment: Exactly. Perhaps the auth token?

Comment: The thing is, I use the same token in the same way for all my other API calls which do work (creating Campaigns, Sets, Custom Audiences, adding users to Custom Audiences, etc.). Images are the only thing not giving me what I want. Thanks for the help! And I will post more questions when I have some more specific details to tell/figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `files`, the POST data is encoded as `multipart/form-data`, which is what you want when posting form data that includes large binary blobs of content.

If you use *just* `data` on the other hand, then `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is used instead (unless you pass in just a string, then data is posted as-is).

For file uploads, you probably want the former, as `multipart/form-data` can also encode the mime-type and filename of the file data. Looking at the [Facebook Ad API adimage enpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adimage/) their samples use `curl -F`, which is documented to use `multipart/form-data` for the upload.

Remember that *also* need to include a `access_token` in the POST:

```
requests.post(endpoint,
    files={'pic.jpg': open('pic.jpg', 'rb')},
    data={'access_token': '___'})
```

This uses both `files` *and* `data`, `requests` will combine both into one `multipart/form-data` POST body.

Also see [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) and [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)